# Redemption Outlook VBA reference always getting reset in Citrix

Tags: vba, ms-access, reference, citrix, outlook-redemption

Every time I enable the Redemption Outlook library in my Access VBA (tools -> references), it seems to get reset when I log out of Citrix. Is there any way to keep it as a persistently-added reference like the others?

Comment: later versions of office should not need redemption to remove nags. Access is considered a signed application, and you should now be free to automatic outlook from access, and without any warning prompts. This would assume office 2010 or later.

Answer (score 0):

It probably means the HKCU registry gets reset. Try to register Redemption with regsvr32.exe from an elevated command prompt - it then will install itself in HKCR.

Comment: Or the server/desktop is stateless, meaning that when it reboots it's back to clean state with exception of (selected items in) the user profile.

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely that the registry entry for this reference simply isn't getting saved permanently when Citrix exits.  Talk to your Citrix admin about adding the registry entries permanently.  Otherwise, rather than running your Access app directly in Citrix, consider running a script in Citrix (vbscript or Powershell) which adds the reference for this to the registry at runtime and then starts your app.